# Chart.js Chart with more than one X-Axis-Scale (Months and Years)

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js, scale

I am trying to draw a chart with chart.js to visually display the occurrence of a specific dates.
I have two different Objects, one that counts on a per-Month basis and one that counts on a per-Year basis.

Here is `summarizedDatesMonth`:

```
[
    {
        "date": "08.2018",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "09.2018",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "10.2018",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "11.2018",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "12.2018",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "01.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "03.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "04.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "05.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "06.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "07.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "08.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "09.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "10.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "11.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "12.2019",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "01.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "02.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "03.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "04.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "05.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "06.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "07.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "08.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "09.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "10.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "11.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "12.2020",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "01.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "02.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "03.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "04.2021",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "05.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "06.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "07.2021",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "08.2021",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "09.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "10.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "11.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "12.2021",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "01.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "02.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "03.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "04.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "05.2022",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "06.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "07.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "08.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "09.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "10.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "11.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "12.2022",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "01.2023",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "02.2023",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "03.2023",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "04.2023",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "05.2023",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "06.2023",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "07.2023",
        "count": 0
    }
]
```

And here is `summarizedDatesYear`:

```
[
    {
        "year": "2018",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "year": "2021",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "year": "2022",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "year": "2023",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

This is my Chart creation:

```
new Chart(instance.popper.querySelector('#chart-canvas'),{
            data: {
              labels: summarizedDatesMonth.map(row => row.date),
              datasets: [
                {
                  type: 'line',
                  label: 'Play times a month',
                  data: summarizedDatesMonth.map(row => row.count),
                  tension: 0.5,
                  spanGaps: true,
                  fill: true,
                },
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: 'Play times a year',
                  data: summarizedDatesYear.map(row => row.count),
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                y: {
                  min: 0,
                },
                /*xAxis: {
                  type: 'time',
                  time: {
                    minUnit: 'month',
                  },
                },*/
              },
              plugins: {
                legend: {
                  display: true,
                },
              },
            },
          });
```

I tried a few different things, but it just won't work as expected. My chart at the moment looks like this:

[chart.js preview where the x-axis is correct witht the line graph and wrong with the bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weNlA.png)

(Please keep in mind that the data provided above does not match the picture chart!!)

What I would like to achieve, is to span the bar chart across the line chart so it maches. In the picture example I provided the first brown bar should end where 12.2019 of the line chart is, the second brown bar should begin at 01.2020 and span through to 12.2020. So that the line chart points are aligned relative to the bar charts.

I tried a few different things, but I can't find any example on how to add two separate time scales. I played with the scales-option of chart.js, I tried to summarize the data like this:

```
const lineChartData = summarizedDatesMonth.map((data) => ({
            x: data.date,
            y: data.count,
          }));
          // Extracting data for the bar chart
          const barChartData = summarizedDatesYear.map((data) => ({
            x: data.year,
            y: data.count,
          }));
```

but nothing worked as expected..

If I change the labels of the data to `summarizedDatesYear.map`, the x-axis shows the years for both the line and bar chart, and i want it only for the year...

I hope you get my point I am miserable at describing my problems.... If you have any questions let me know!

I would greatly appreciate any help!

## Edit

I managed to do it but it is a dirty way, however it works.

I just took the `summarizedDatesMonth` and summed the year up, so the `summarizedDatesYear` now has the same amount of values. it works for now, but if anybody has a better solution, i'd be happy!

[this is how it looks right now, i just need to red rid of the border in between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQvsB.png)